# Can We Speak of the "Prime Factorizations" of the Positive Rationals?

Tags: terminology, prime-factorization

I am of two minds with respect to this question;  therefore I will lay out the case for the existence of prime factorizations of positive rationals such as $2.5$ or $\frac{22}{7}$, and then I will lay out the case for their nonexistence.

The prime factorization of any natural number $n \ge 2$ is a product of its prime factors such that the product evaluates to $n$; we are guaranteed by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic that the product is unique up to the order of the factors.  Thus we may write $40$ as
$2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 5$, or more briefly in exponential form as $2^3 \cdot 5^1$.  Let us look at the generalized exponential form of the prime factorization of $n$:

$n = p_{a_1}^{b_1} \cdots p_{a_k}^{b_k}$,

where $p_{a_{i}}$ is the $i$th prime factor of $n$, $p_{a_{k}}$ is the greatest prime factor of $n$, and $(b_{1}, \ldots b_{k})$ is the unique sequence of positive integers satisfying the equation.

But let us now relax our requirement that the integers $b_{i}$ in $(b_{i})_{i=1}^{k}$ be positive, allowing negative integers to be included as well. Then we could write $5.6$, for example, as

$2^2 \cdot 5^{-1} \cdot 7^{1}$.

Observe that the above expression bears a striking resemblance to the exponential form of prime factorization. Indeed, just as with prime factorization, the expression is unique up to the order of its factors, since $5.6$ can be uniquely expressed as the reduced fraction $\frac{28}{5}$, the numerator and denominator each corresponding to unique prime factorizations:

$5.6 = \frac{28}{5} = \frac{2\times 2 \times 7}{5}$.

On the other hand, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic only addresses integers greater than 1.  Also, prime factorizations are frequently written without use of exponentiation (as I illustrated with $40$ above); this is impossible if negative exponents are permitted.  For instance, there is no integer $k$ satisfying

$5.6 = 2 \times 2 \times \underbrace{5 \times \cdots \times 5}_{k \text{ $5$s}} \times 7$.

So in one respect it appears we can generalize prime factorization so that every positive rational number $q$ has a prime factorization (the prime factorization of 1 being vacuously 1 itself), yet in another respect it appears such a generalization is not possible.

Can we speak generally of "the prime factorizations of positive rationals," then, or not?  And if not, what would be the proper term denoting such objects?

Comment: Yes, every rational can be uniquely written as a finite product $\prod_p_i^{\alpha_i}$ where $p_i$ are prime and $\alpha_i\in\Bbb Z$. I'm not aware of any specific name of this.

Comment: I'd call it *expression of a rational number as a product of integer powers of primes*. If I wanted to be a little more careful, I'd insert the word *nontrivial* in front of "integer".

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I can think of certain situations where it would be very useful to regard such expressions as generalizations of prime factorization, with interesting consequences arising from extension of the concept. Surely someone in the past must have thought of a short and easily-remembered name for such critters.

Comment: The positive rational numbers, as a multiplicative group, is a free abelian group on countably many generators (namely the positive primes).

Comment: It is very useful, I don't deny that for a minute, I just can't recall seeing a short name for it.

Comment: If we allow the "vacous factorization" of $1$, we can of course define the factorization uniquely by factoring numerator and denominator with the additional property that they are coprime (pari/gp actually handles it this way). Do you have something else in mind, namely that the rational numbers can be prime and we write a rational number as a product of "rational primes" ?

Comment: In the first case, we just have the "quotient of two prime factorizations" , if we want we can additionally allow negative exponents, but I am not aware of a common name of that.

Comment: @Peter you were close when you asked if I was trying to write a rational number as a product of "rational primes."  I was developing a numeral system in which every rational number is uniquely represented by a Dyck word.  See "Recursive Prime Factorizations: Dyck Words as Numbers" (arXiv:2102.02777), Section 3.1.